# How to visualize the 3D region in using Fubini's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have problem in visualizing the region in the Fubini's theorem usage (I have no problem with the usage of Funibi's theroem itself). The region is bounded by $x=0,~z=y^2,~z=x,~z=1.$ I often visualize such region by luck, but not any clever thought. However, when regions becomes a little more diffcult, like this one, it's pretty hard for me to visualize such region. Is there a clever or easy way to do so? Or is there any systematical way?

PS: I always try to draw something like:
[image]

But when the case is too complicated, I'll get lost in the figure..

Comment: slight misspell of 'Finibi'